# Putting a mirror on the inside of a wardrobe door

Tags: doors, carpentry, bedroom, mirror, shelf

How can I put a mirror on the inside of a wardrobe if the shelves come all the way to the door?

[image: cabinet with right door open]

[image: close up of shelf almost touching door]

[image: cabinet with left door open]

[image: wider shot of door almost touching shelf]

[image: Different angle with right door open]

Comment: Cut the edge of the shelves to make room for the mirror. How about a picture of the shelves and door.

Comment: @JACK I've attached some pictures of the wardrobe. The doors are "push open"

Comment: use a mylar mirror, that should be thin enough to fit tn the crack between the door and the shelves.

Comment: @Jasen thanks for the suggestion - that's probably what we will end up doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to remove the shelves and have the and have the edges cut to make room for the mirror.

There's a possibility that the actual hinges and opener could be adjusted to allow for the additional space. The mirror could be assembled using mirror tiles from your home store and heavy duty double sided tape.

As a last resort, you could mount a mirror on the wall inside the cabinet... of course you'd loose some hang up space. The mirror could also be mounted on the outside of the door which might work better since the doors only open 90 degrees.

Comment: @Jasen  If you zoom in on the first picture, you can see the shelve supports. the shelves probably just sit on top of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cut the back of each shelf the mirror will touch.   As it isn't exposed cutting the MDF shouldn't effect the look.

You will also need to buy a pretty light weight and thin mirror and just glue it (adhesive caulk) it to the door.

Answer (score 0):

Get stick-on mylar mirror sheets.   You won't have to trim the shelves and you'll avoid having the heavy weight of a glass mirror swinging back and forth on those hinges.  Those cabinets are not built for that.